# Getting value of a <li> tag to TextField

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am getting search results from a MySQL table from a string entered in an input text from a HTML page.

Using AJAX, when the user selects one of the result rows the browser is redirected to a PHP file.

What I need is to put the result on another TextField from the same page and not to open another page.

Here is the code that I have now:

PHP part that is sending the needed output results:

```
/************************************************
    Search Functionality
************************************************/

// Define Output HTML Formating
$html = '';

$html .= '<li class="result" >';
$html .= '<img src="iconos_especialidades/logo"  width="94" height="94"  />';
$html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString" >';
$html .= '   '.'<h3>nameString</h3>';
$html .= '</a>';
$html .= '</li>';

// Get Search
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

// Check Length More Than One Character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    // Build Query
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM tb_especialidades WHERE especialidad LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR especialidad LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" ORDER BY especialidad';

    // Do Search
    $result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
    while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array[] = $results;
    }

    // Check If We Have Results
    if (isset($result_array)) {
        foreach ($result_array as $result) {

            // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
            $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['especialidad']);
            $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['especialidad']);
            $display_url = 'opinar_doc_loc.php?id='.$result['id_especialidad'];

            if ($result['icono'] == ""){
            $display_logo = "nada.jpg";
            }
            else {
            $display_logo = $result['icono'] ;
            }

            // Insert Name
            $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);



            // Insert URL
            $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);
            // Insert LOGO
            $output = str_replace('logo', $display_logo, $output);
            // Output
            echo($output);
        }
    }else{

        // Format No Results Output
        $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
        $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>No se ha encontrado la especialidad buscada.</b>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);
        // Insert LOGO
            $display_logo = "nada.jpg";
            $output = str_replace('logo', $display_logo, $output);

        // Output
        echo($output);
    }
}
```

And here is the JQuery/Ajax Part:

```
// Start Ready
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').text(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/search.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }

    $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));

        };
    });

});
```

How could I put the needed value from the database **$result['id_especialidad']** on a TextField from the HTML page?

Comment: I'm not sure of your intentions here. What do you mean by TextField? Do you mean an input field? Maybe you mean a paragraph tag or similar?

Comment: @DavidBattersby, yes, I mean to put the selected result as text in a text field

Comment: an "onChange" trigger will fix you problem?

Comment: @AngeloBerzacola, I guess that won't fix the problem, then I think that it is not possible to use it on a <li> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by returning a json object with more than one key. For example from php:

```
<?php
  $result = array('id' => $result['id_especialidad'], 'data' => $output);
  echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Then from JS you can decode and handle as two separate pieces of data:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/search.php",
  data: { query: query_value },
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    var response = $.parseJSON(html);
    $("#my_input_field").val(response.id);
    $("ul#results").html(response.data);
   }
 });
```

EDIT -------

I've added the correct id field from the query result (see above again), you will also need to edit the output from the no results part of the php file (after the 'else') to echo the json encoded array... for example:

```
<?php
  $result = array('id' => 0, 'data' => $output);
  echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it now

Comment: It doesn't work David, if I put var response = $.parseJSON(html); then the list is not shown. The PHP part works fine

Comment: I've updated my answer, if there are no results the php needs to return an array also, I've defaulted the id to 0 in this case

Comment: Thank you again, but your proposal doesn't work. The results list isn't shown

Comment: @mvasco Are you getting any kind of error from the developer console (JS), also check the php error log. Any info might help solve this issue.

Comment: If you console.log(response) within the ajax success callback what gets outputted to the console?

Comment: 11:07:14.576 SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 311 of the JSON data
f</<.parseJSON() jquery.min.js:2
search/<.success() custom.js:23
f.Callbacks/n() jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks/o.fireWith() jquery.min.js:2
w() jquery.min.js:4
.send/d() jquery.min.js:4
1 jquery.min.js:2:11013

Comment: It looks like the string ($output) is not formatted correctly from PHP and this is why it is breaking when parsed as JSON. I'd suggest printing the value of $output to the log and checking it is formatted correctly.

Comment: I will check it again, thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a little bit confusing...

After click in the result list (LIs), you want to put the redirect page to a text field instead of open a new page ?

If yes, you need to do another ajax to get the page content and them put the content in the text field.

Comment: Sorry for my english... What I need is to put the selected result from the list as text in a text field